# Is this a reasonable, robust way for detecting voltage crossing a threshold?

Tags: relay, comparator

**Updated, functional design at the bottom of this question**

I wish to detect when a low-impedance signal is below or above 60VDC (±3V). When the signal is above 60V, I'd like to indicate this by illuminating an LED and opening a relay. Else, illuminate another LED and close the relay.

To do this I propose to use a the following comparator circuit. This is my best attempt - I've made functional blocks and connected them together as best as I can see. Is it a reasonable design?

[image: Proposed Design]

Here is my justification for each part of the circuit:

HV is the a low-impedance 0-200VDC signal which is divided by 20, so that when HV=60V, the inverting input at the comparator should be approx 3V. Multiple resistors are used within the voltage divider to ensure manageable voltages across each resistor.
A reference voltage of 3.0V is applied to the noninverting input.

When HV < 60V, the comparator output should be high, which drives the relay through Q1, and illuminates D2.
When HV > 60V, the comparator output should be low, which de-energises the relay and illuminates D4.

The comparator output is an open-collector, so R8 acts as a pullup.

The 12V zener at the inverting input is included to provide transient protection.

I have not included input-offset adjustment because this circuit should not be user-adjustable. I've picked a comparator with acceptably low input offset voltage and high accuracy is not a concern.

R6, R7 and C3 seem to be best-practice inclusions - I haven't done this before but I think they eliminate oscillation of the output caused by capacitive coupling between output and input. I've included these components provisionally but may decide against them.

I've avoided adding positive feedback for hysteresis because I'm having trouble including it without shifting the switching thresholds (drastically). Since this circuit is for a visual indicator only, I'm not overly concerned if the output chatters about the switching threshold - HV should never be steady close to 60V. If there is a painless way to add a few tens-of-millivolts hysteresis, I'd love to hear it. I've considered just adding some small capacitance to the output.

*Side note*:
I'm acutely aware there's probably a very elegant means of doing this with a high-voltage linear regulator referenced by zener diode - a huge advantage there would be the ability to change the trigger voltage by changing only the zener - and doing away with voltage divider and comparator entirely. I don't have the analog-confidence to venture into that realm, but if you have any thoughts I'd love to hear them.

### EDIT - an updated design

Thanks for your feedback everyone.
Based off feedback from commentors I arrived with the following design. It performs acceptably when constructed and tested - VHI:62V, VLO:59V. The circuit is basically the same as the first proposed, but with a modified output-circuit. I'm more comfortable with voltage controlled devices like MOSFETs so they were used instead of BJTs. A comparator with reasonably low input-offset was selected to make this a build-and-forget design. It should not be necessary to tune the circuit.
[image]

There are plenty of undesirable failure modes - I'm aware. Read the full writeup on the [readme](https://github.com/michaelruppe/FSAE/tree/master/TSAL).

Comment: You realize that the circuit is not going to switch at **exactly** 60V, don't you? What is the acceptable range of switching voltages?

Comment: I realise that - give or take a couple of volts is acceptable. I'll update the question.

Comment: "*I've avoided adding positive feedback for hysteresis because I'm having trouble including it without shifting the switching thresholds.*" That's the whole idea of hysteresis. A [hysteresis calculator](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Comparator-Hystereses-Calculator.phtml) may help.

Comment: I think D4 will continuously light up as Q2 will **never be off**. For Q4 to be off, it's base voltage needs to be close to 12 V and that will not happen, the comparator's output can never go above ~0.7 V (Vbe of Q1). I would make use the voltage at the collector of Q1 to control the base of Q4. Note that the LM2903  has an **open collector** output, it can only pull to ground.

Comment: @Transistor those calculators seem to always assume a push-pull output. This is an open-collector output.

Comment: Have you considered this fault condition? : The "HV" plug or cable is disconnected or open.

Comment: See [hysteresis-calculation-for-open-collector-output-comparator-with-a-pull-up-res](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221265/hysteresis-calculation-for-open-collector-output-comparator-with-a-pull-up-res).

Comment: TI also have a document [Inverting comparator with hysteresis circuit](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa997/snoa997.pdf) and this appears to cover open-drain / open-collector arrangements.

Comment: While hysteresis might sound "scary" it isn't that difficult to do the design calculations. Just consider two separate cases, output is high and output is low. That gives you two input threshold voltages (where the comparator's inputs have the same voltage). If you would replace Q4 with an NMOS then you would increase the comparator's output voltage swing. That could also solve the issue I mentioned above btw. (I'd use a PMOS for Q2 then also).

Comment: What is the power source on this board? Is it a transformer? Is this for AC mains autodetection?

Comment: Additional errors with the original design: 1. No power supply connection shown for U1. 2. If the comparator supply is 12V, should choose a lower threshold value for D1 to ensure it clamps below the comparator's absmax Vin for over-voltage inputs. 3. It's best not to connect the inputs of an unused comparator (U1B) to the same voltage. This will consume more power as it's an unstable condition for the internal amplification circuitry.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it a reasonable design?

No, it looks too complicate to me. A TL431 (and a 2-resistors voltage divider) can replace the left half of your diagram, using 3 components only.

The right part can be mostly replaced using gates made out of transistors or diodes. A NOR-gate, as an example, can be done with 1 transistor only. Or you can use a normal transistor and a depletion mode one, both bases activated by the TL431 (ie: when voltage is high, the TL431 turns on the normal transistor, and turns off the depletion mode one). Beware TL431 can't supply much current, but you can use mosfets...

Just a quick circuit diagram to give you the whole idea:

[image]

In this example you don't need the DC-DC converter to get the 12v and if you add a little transformer you can isolate the low voltage part from the high voltage one (safety). The optocoupler is there not because there's the need of it, but its transistor can drive bigger loads than the TL431 alone; I placed the optocoupler instead of a transistor just to introduce the idea of using a transformer to isolate the high voltage part from the low voltage one.

Resistors are in circuit, so they will burn some current, but considering the load made of 2 leds and a transistor, isn't much. Just be sure their power rating is enough.
In the case you need more than 1/4 or 1/2 watt resistors and you can't source bigger ones, you can split the power rail and use one resistor for each of the devices in the right part of the circuit. Just be sure that those devices can work with high voltage, or you'll have to make more voltage dividers. All this, of course, is to avoid the DC-DC converter as you asked in the comments.

Comment: I appreciate the idea contribution - care to include a schematic to make things a little clearer? I looked into how I might use this device and it doesn't appear to be simpler to me once I include supporting components. Moving away from having to use a DC-DC converter is a great plus though. I've just stuck with what I know.

Comment: Answer updated with example circuit and notes.

Comment: Where can we get a "depletion mode" BJT? Why is the transistor base shorted to ground?

Comment: You can find it in the same shop where you buy normal transistors! In any case, you can use a normal transistor changing a bit the circuit (search for "transistor not gate"). The base is not shorted to ground; the entire circuit is after the 1k resistor at the top left, so the transistor base is as well.

Comment: Can you tell me an example of a part number for a "depletion mode" BJT? Not an FET, but a BJT. Also, the base of the transistor is **directly and obviously** wired to ground. The base connection goes left to pin 4 of the optoisolator, then straight down to the horizontal wire which connects to a symbol labeled GND.

Comment: I can't see any on digikey catalog. You made me the doubt they don't exist. Anyway, a mosfet is better because uses less current. In general, as I wrote, that's just a quick and dirty draft. To make it a working circuit would take much more time than what I've spent. The same applies to your question about the transistor base: it depends on what kind of transistor it will be used, you may need to pull up/down the base. I just wanted to point out that his design was too complicate and parts count cound be taken from 20+ to 10- ... the opto can be removed as well, using the tl431 directly.

Comment: The whole point of my answer is to make him look at new parts (ex: tl431, optos, depletion mode transistors) because to use 20+ parts to exec a simple function (voltage treshold) is ... crazy. Increasing complexity means more cost, more points of failure, and so on. Complexity must be increased only and only if strictly needed. And this is not the case, given the task simplicity. You should note that I didn't include the relay in my draft, as it was not intended to give a working solution, just place him on a different path...

Comment: @ElliotAlderson (continue from previous 2 comments) He asked "Is it a reasonable design?". And my answer has been "no, it's too complicate, try this other way". Actually, I'm going to make this explicit in my answer... to avoid further misunderstanding.

Comment: But the answer you provided was not useful and not helpful. It obviously and clearly could not function. If you can't provide a proper design suggestion, don't say anything at all...you just mislead the reader.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson If I would use the same mindset with you, you shouldn't have commented because, as an example, you wrote "short" (ie: directly connecting V+ and V-) instead of "wired" (any connection). You're not useful (because you didn't provide an answer to his question) and not helpful (because you spend time discussing in comments instead of helping him). But, let's forget about this for a moment and focus on the subject. The transistor there is just the most basic symbol I could find in kicad, as to make a proper circuit would take too long. Just forget it and imagine the right one.

Comment: Sorry, no, a "short" is not necessarily a connection from V+ and V-...it is an undesirable low resistance path between any two points in a circuit. And the problem is that the OP **cannot** "imagine the right one". They think that **you** gave them the right one.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it is clearly stated in the answer "Just a quick circuit diagram to give you the whole idea", and I doubled the warning in the picture (gigantic "DRAFT" note). Everything is wrong in that picture: there's the need to do the math - power wise - before I can place the proper resistors, and in order to know the proper math, the transistor must be defined, and the relay introduced... so we know the load/power. There might be the need to split the load across more than 1 voltage divider, or go back to the dc-dc converter. That circuit is just a concept, an idea. Understand now?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson please Elliot, stop biting my words and go back to work. I can't keep discussing on insignificant details. I agree with your definition of "short", my definition was just a shortcut to save time. The key point, AGAIN, is another one. I specified 1k on the upper resistor exactly to avoid an "undesirable low resistance path" (aka "short"), and 1k is a relatively high resistance for that case, so again: the base is "wired" to gnd but not "shorted" to gnd.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ... and yes, they can and MUST imagine, because (1) I didn't write ANY part identifier. In other words I didn't give them any, so it can't be wrong. Moreover, (2) there's no relay in circuit. In other words: if they want to make that circuit fit in their circumstances (ie: turn on a relay), they MUST rework the circuit anyway. And once they rework it, they'll figure out the missing parts and details. The question, again, is about the original design: is it reasonable? Answer: no, it isn't. My (not working) circuit, is added value only.